# Как обработать нажатие на TextView, в котором есть ссылка?

Tags: android, kotlin, link, listener

Пишу приложение под Android на kotlin. Во фрагменте у меня есть TextView, в котором имеется ссылка. Вешаю обработчик нажатия на TextView, но он не срабатывает (как я понял, из-за наличия ссылки). Нужно, чтобы по нажатию на TextView срабатывал onClickListener, а по нажатию на ссылку - осуществлялся переход по ней. Как это реализовать?

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_content"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/common_spacing"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/common_spacing"
        android:autoLink="web"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/header"
        tools:text="@sample/posts.json/data/content" />
```

Можно у TextView установить атрибут: android:linksClickable="false". Тогда сработает слушатель по нажатию на текст, но по ссылке перехода не будет. Надеюсь на вашу помощь!

Comment: там только ссылка будет, или и другой текст тоже?

Comment: @Andrew Сначала обычный текст, а в конце ссылка

Comment: С точки зрения UX, вам стоит разделить на два контрола: один для обычного нажатия, второй для ссылки. Либо по нажатию показывать контекстное меню с выбором под-действия. Т.е. нажатие на текстовое поле может иметь только одно действие.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как принятый нажав на галочку слева от него.

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант можно сделать регулярное выражение которое будет искать ссылку:

```
private val urlPattern: Pattern = Pattern.compile(
    "(?:^|[\\W])((ht|f)tp(s?):/\\/|www\\.)"
            + "(([\\w\\-]+\\.){1,}?([\\w\\-.~]+/?)*"
            + "[\\p{Alnum}.,%_=?&#\\-+()\\[\\]*$~@!:/{};']*)",
    Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE or Pattern.MULTILINE or Pattern.DOTALL
)
```

дальше я для примера сделал метод, который обрабатывает текст с несколькими ссылками:

```
private fun getHyperLinks(s: String): List<String> {
    val urlList = mutableListOf<String>()
    val urlMatcher = urlPattern.matcher(s)
    var matchStart: Int
    var matchEnd: Int


    while (urlMatcher.find()) {
        matchStart = urlMatcher.start(1)
        matchEnd = urlMatcher.end()

        val url = s.substring(matchStart, matchEnd)
        urlList.add(url)
    }
    return urlList
}
```

и для примера парсил такой текст:

```
getHyperLinks("foo bar https://google.com http://google.com")
```

в вашем случае если ссылка будет одна, то можно сделать слушатель нажатий на виджет:

```
txtView.setOnClickListener {
   val url = getHyperLinks("foo bar https://google.com http://google.com")[0]
   val i = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW)
   i.setData(Uri.parse(url))
   startActivity(i)
}
```

либо добавить вытаскивание ссылок то что в методе в обработку нажатий по виджету. Либо вообще возвращать одну только ссылку из метода при условии что в строке где будет искаться она будет одна:

```
private fun getHyperLinks(s: String): String {
    var link = ""
    val urlMatcher = urlPattern.matcher(s)

    while (urlMatcher.find()) {
        val matchStart = urlMatcher.start(1)
        val matchEnd = urlMatcher.end()

        link = s.substring(matchStart, matchEnd)
        break
    }

    return link
}
```

Вот здесь хорошие статьи: [раз](https://proandroiddev.com/parse-long-texts-to-get-clickable-links-with-kotlin-in-android-3fc7536efaed), [два](https://anant-raman.medium.com/extract-hyperlinks-and-emails-from-a-text-and-perform-actions-in-android-kotlin-5483fe74da5e) и [три](https://medium.com/@gkulabukhov/custom-clickable-links-in-textview-7d8fba5ec770)

Answer (score 0):

Код:

```
TextView tv = findViewById( R.id.tv );
tv.setMovementMethod( LinkMovementMethod.getInstance() );
tv.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener(){
    @Override
    public void onClick( View view ){
        Toast.makeText( Main.this, "CLICK!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();
    }
} );
```

Строка из ресурса:

```
<string name="text_with_link">This is a simple text. <a href="https://google.com">Google</a> </string>
```

Фрагмент разметки:

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/text_with_link"
    android:id="@+id/tv"
    />
```

Протестировал, работает: ссылка открывается без уведомления, а прикосновение к остальному тексту вызывает уведомление.